# Simultaneous equations change expression variables

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, systems-of-equations, problem-solving, change-of-basis

I have a deceptively simple-looking problem.

$$A + B = A'\\
C + D = B'\\
A + C = C'\\
B + D = D'$$

On LHS $4$ variables $A,  B,  C,  D$
On RHS $4$ variables $A', B', C', D'$

Is it possible to express $A$ in terms of any of the ' variables alone?
 i.e find $A = f(A', B', C', D'), B = g(A', B', C', D')$, e.t.c.

Intuitively it seems there should be a relatively simple way to re-express LHS variables in terms of RHS variables. But I'm starting to think maybe that intuition is wrong?

a) If so, how do I do it?, is there some kind of general method? What is it called?

b) If not, prove it is not possible (ideally other than brute force). Is this a known/studied problem? Do you have any references? What is it called?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have $B-C=A'-C'$ and also $B-C=D'-B'$. So there are no solutions unless $A'+B'=C'+D'$. If that holds then only three of the equations are independent, so you can fix $A$ arbitrarily, say $A=x$ and then $B=A'-x,C=C'-x,D=D'-A'+x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing this in terms of matrices, you have:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}A\\B\\C\\D\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}A'\\B'\\C'\\D'\end{bmatrix}.
$$

We can write $A,\cdots,D$ in terms of $A',\cdots,D'$ iff the matrix is invertible.  Since the determinant of $A$ is zero, this is not possible.

More precisely, observe that $A=B=C=D=0$ and $A=D=1$, $B=C=-1$ give the same RHS of $A'=B'=C'=D'=0$.

In other words, for any valid $A'$, $B'$, $C'$, and $D'$, there are infinitely many $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$'s that satisfy the equations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know that a solution is trivial and infinitely many solutions are possible. My question is how to express each unprimed variable in terms of primed variables, not find  a solution. ☺

Comment: Having re-read I see the determinant is 0 therefore it is non-invertible, therefore this is not possible. Thank you.